# Python + KvMD: Logger.exception("{}: Error when building app".format(self.appname)) Message: 'MagicMenuConcept: Error when building app' Arguments:

Tags: python, menu, kivy, kivymd

I'm starting in this language and I'm encountering this error.

It should display a drop-down menu of icons, but it gives this error when compiling.
I have already tried the related posts here on the forum for this error.
I've searched the internet and I can't figure it out.

Could someone help me please?

```
main.py

import importlib
import os

from kivy import Config
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from PIL import ImageGrab
from kivy.core.window import Window

from kivymd.tools.hotreload.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager


#- Resolução monitor
resolution = ImageGrab.grab().size

Config.set("graphics", "height", resolution[0])
Config.set("graphics", "width", 400)

Window.top  = 0
Window.left = resolution[0] - Window.width

# class Gerenciador(MDScreenManager):
#     pass

class MagicMenuConcept(MDApp):
    KV_DIRS = {os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "magicmenu")}

    def buld_app(self) -> MDScreen:
        import magicmenu.magic_menu

        importlib.reload(magicmenu.magic_menu)

        magic_menu = magicmenu.magic_menu.MagicMenu()

        magic_menu.generate_menu()

        screen = MDScreen()
        screen.add_widget(magic_menu)

        return screen

    def on_keyboard_down(self, window, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers) -> None:
        if "meta" in modifiers or "ctrl" in modifiers and text == "r":
            self.rebuild

# fmagicmenu = MagicMenuConcept()
# print(fmagicmenu)
# fmagicmenu.run()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MagicMenuConcept().run()
```

```
magic_menu.py

#from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivy.properties import DictProperty, NumericProperty, ColorProperty
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.tooltip import MDTooltip


class ElevationCard(RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior, MDCard):
    """ Implementa a classe base para um Card com comportamento(Behavior) de elevação """


class MenuButton(MDIconButton, MDTooltip):
    """ Implementa o botão para o Magic Menu """


class MagicMenu(ElevationCard):
    """ Implementa a classe base para o Magic Menu """
    pos_marker = NumericProperty(0)
    color_marker = ColorProperty([0,0,0,0])

    menu_buttons = DictProperty(
        {
            "home":"Red",
            "account": "Indigo",
            "message": "Teal",
            "help": "Yellow",
            "close": "BlueGray",
        })

    def generate_menu(self):
        """ Gera os botões do menu """

        spacing_button = dp(12)
        start_position = dp(6)

        for i, name_icon in enumerate(self.menu_buttons.keys()):
            start_position += spacing_button
            menu_button = MenuButton(icon=name_icon)
            menu_button.y = (
                    self.height - (menu_button.height * (i + 1) + start_position)
            )

            menu_button.bind(on_enter=self.set_menu_marker)

            self.ids.buttons_container.add_widget(menu_button)

        self.set_menu_marker(self.ids.buttons_container.children[-1])

    def set_menu_marker(self, instance_menu_button: MenuButton):
        """ Seleciona a cor e a posição da área de cor para o menu item selecionado """
        anim = Animation(
            pos_marker=instance_menu_button.y - dp(16),
            color_marker=get_color_from_hex(color[self.menu_buttons[instance_menu_button.icon]]["500"]),
            t="in_out_sine",
            d=0.3
        )

        anim.bind(on_complete=self.set_screen_color)
        anim.start(self)

    def set_screen_color(self, *args):
        """ Seleciona a cor de fundo da janela """
        anim = Animation(
            md_bg_color=self.color_marker,
            t="in_out_sine",
            d=0.3
        )

        anim.start(self)
```

```
magic_menu.kv

<MenuButton>
    pos_hint: ("center_x": .5)
    icon_size: "32sp"
    tooltip_text: root.icon.capitalize()
    tooltip_bg_color: self.cls.bg_dark
    tooltip_text_color: 0,0,0,1
    shift_y: self.height
    shift_right: dp(96)


<MagicMenu>
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "84dp", "320dp"
    pos_hint: {"center_x", .5, "center_y": .5}
    radius: self.width / 2
    elevation: 8

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: root.color_marker
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.x + dp(6), self.y + dp(6) + root.pos_marker
            size: self.width - dp(12), self.width - dp(12)
            radius: [(self.width - dp(12)) / 2]

    MDRelativeLayout:
        id: buttons_container
```

```
“ --- Logging error ---
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivymd\tools\hotreload\app.py", line 284, in rebuild
     self.approot = self.build_app()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivymd\tools\hotreload\app.py", line 227, in build_app
     raise NotImplementedError()
 NotImplementedError
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1083, in emit
     msg = self.format(record)
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 927, in format
     return fmt.format(record)
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivy\logger.py", line 291, in format
     record = copy.deepcopy(record)
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 172, in deepcopy
     y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 270, in _reconstruct
     state = deepcopy(state, memo)
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
     y = copier(x, memo)
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 230, in _deepcopy_dict
     y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 146, in deepcopy
     y = copier(x, memo)
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in _deepcopy_tuple
     y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 210, in <listcomp>
     y = [deepcopy(a, memo) for a in x]
   File "C:\Users\luana\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
     rv = reductor(4)
 TypeError: cannot pickle 'traceback' object
 Call stack:
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\main.py", line 52, in <module>
     MagicMenuConcept().run()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivymd\tools\hotreload\app.py", line 195, in build
     self.rebuild(first=True)
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivymd\tools\hotreload\app.py", line 290, in rebuild
     Logger.exception("{}: Error when building app".format(self.appname))
 Message: 'MagicMenuConcept: Error when building app'
 Arguments: ()
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\main.py", line 52, in <module>
     MagicMenuConcept().run()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
     self._run_prepare()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924, in _run_prepare
     root = self.build()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivymd\tools\hotreload\app.py", line 195, in build
     self.rebuild(first=True)
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivymd\tools\hotreload\app.py", line 284, in rebuild
     self.approot = self.build_app()
   File "C:\Sistemas\Python\Exemplos\Componentes\Magic Menu\lib\site-packages\kivymd\tools\hotreload\app.py", line 227, in build_app
     raise NotImplementedError()
 NotImplementedError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).